# Play Transparent Video

Tags: swift, swiftui

I was sent a video (made in after effects) with an alpha channel (has transparency). I need to add that video to an iOS app, like adding a transparent GIF.

There is [this](https://medium.com/@quentinfasquel/ios-transparent-video-in-swiftui-92a9a1cce94e) tutorial online on how to do just that, however he is using a single mp4 that displays alpha info on the bottom and the colour info on the top, I am using Quicktime 444 which is already transparent by nature. Is there anyway I can play a transparent video on Swift for iOS? I am using SwiftUI.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @tail Hello! No need for any code since there is no code causing any problems but rather the lack of code, the lack of code that is needed to place a transparent video in SwiftUI.